# store date and time in Database Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am newbie in Cakephp 2.3.6 and have never worked with date and time .. what i want  is to make a select box into my view page in which all countries and their time etc are displaying and user  select the time and date and then it will then save into database ... i didnt find any cakephp 2.3 helpful tutorials for this .. and neither i understand the documentation ..
i just want to have a select box in which all countries times are displaying as you have seen in some websites too.. ifollowed this tutorial but it is giving me errors .http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=37075  ..if some one has implemented this functionality then please help me also tell me how to i echo the time and data after retrieving from db in this format

data :24Feb
  time : 10:30pm

Comment: I’m having trouble determining what you’re wanting to store: the current date and time in a particular country, or the country’s timezone offset?

Comment: http://www.google.com.pk/imgres?sa=X&biw=1304&bih=707&tbm=isch&tbnid=_nUDwrRI3e6VEM:&imgrefurl=http://www.zoho.com/crm/help/administration/manage-crm-account-settings.html&docid=eWzg5DckVoj5JM&imgurl=http://www.zoho.com/crm/help/img/country-locale.png&w=555&h=238&ei=WjTIUci1DMrc4QSf2oCoAg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:4,s:0,i:89&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=147&tbnw=342&start=0&ndsp=13&tx=75&ty=92  this is what i want

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with that? It is dead easy to do: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper::format Just lookup what you need to format your date like you want.

If you need to convert the stored time to another time zone when outputting the date see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper::convert

And http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/time.html#TimeHelper::listTimezones will get you the list you need for the select.

Comment: For three of the two methods there is sample code provided within the documentation I've linked and listTimezones() does not really need any word of documentation... If you want me to do your work and write code for you you can hire me and pay me.